# KY-008 laser diode module: how is the 5mW power rating explained

Tags: laser-diode

I am puzzled by this "5mW"" rating and wonder if someone can explain it.

Current rating is 30mA under 5V so the total input power is 150mW.
With a voltage drop across the diode of 2.2V the power through the diode is 66mW.
Assuming a typical 20% efficiency the output (optical) power should then be about 13mW.

Where does this 5mW rating come from?  Or what is it that I misunderstand?

Comment: There's no real datasheet, so who really knows, but a good assumption is that the *steady state* current draw is less than 30mA, and that number is just accounting for inrush current or general fudge factor. In fact if you go looking for info on this thing you can find spec sheets saying it's "20mA", "30mA", or "less than 40mA".

Comment: Or the 5mW could also be an outright fabrication to make the thing easy to sell. Or both.

Comment: A link to the datasheet for the module would be very helpful. Without it we don't know what "this '5mW' rating' means.